# SaveFileDialog displaying only file with specific extension

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I want to save an image which has two options (.Png or .Jpeg),so i need to display only files with **Png and Jpeg format**, like when we choose *Save type as* **All Images** it displays all kind of images in the dialog.
so how would i do that?

```
using(SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
{
     saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (*.Png + Jpeg)|*.Png + *.Jpeg";
}
```

Comment: Possible dup. I'm pretty sure I've seen this here before...

Comment: Sad to see a downvote for no obvious reason.

Comment: @jdmcnair this's not duplicate ... but you haven't even read the question, the answer in your link is not what i was looking for.

Comment: @jdmcnair if you check Spender answer and your link part "I figure it out, this is how you do it: " you will see the different, i asked a simple question of how to show many files extensions in one type like `*.bmp;*.jpeg;*.png"` not many files extensions in multi types. that's the different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd be looking for a filter like this:

```
"Images (*.png,*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpeg";
```

or optionally:

```
"Images (*.png,*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*"
```

Comment: the second line is wrong and will rise an exception!
the correct form is:  
`"Images (*.png,*.jpeg)|*.png|*.jpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*"`